# How can I use ng-if with ionicPopup

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-model

I'm trying to do so, when I click on the send button a popup appears, where if the person enters the correct message it goes to the next screen if not it stays on the screen that is.

my code :
my controller.js

```
.controller('loginController', function($scope, $stateParams, $ionicPopup, $ionicHistory, $state) {

  $scope.Enviar = function(){


            var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.prompt({
              title: 'Login',
              template: 'Pergunta: Digite a P∴S∴ do AP∴?',
              inputType: 'text',
              inputPlaceholder: 'Digite a senha',
              ng-model="login"
            });
            confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
               if(res) {
                  $state.go('app.home');

               } else {
                  console.log('teste');
                  $state.go('login');
               }
            })
  }

})
```

my login.html

```
<ion-view view-title="login">
  <ion-content class="login-principal" scroll="true">
     <div class="login-imagem">
      <img class="full-image" ng-src="img/GOMB.jpg">
     </div>
     <div>
        <ion-list class="list-inset">
          <ion-item class="item-input">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-email-outline placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail">
          </ion-item> 
          <ion-item class="item-input">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-locked-outline placeholder-icon"></i>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Senha">
          </ion-item> 
        </ion-list>
        <div class="row login">
            <div class = "col col-50" >
              <a class="button button-block button-dark" ui-sref="app.cadastroUsuario">Criar conta</a>
            </div>
            <div class = "col col-50" >  
              <a class="button button-block button-dark" ng-click="Enviar()">Entrar</a>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>  
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

My question is how to use ng-model and ng-if with ionicPopup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.Enviar = function(){
            var obj = new String("boa");

            $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                    disableBack : true
            })

            var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.prompt({
              title: 'Login',
              template: 'Pergunta: Digite a?',
              inputType: 'text',
              inputPlaceholder: 'Digite em minusculo'
            });
            confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
               if(res == obj) {
                  $state.go('app.home');
                  console.log(res);
               } else {
                  //console.log('teste');
                  $state.go('login');
                  //console.log(res);
               }
            })
  }
```

Comment: And your this answer is irrelevant to your own question. You asked if ng-if / ng-model can be used in Ionic popup. Don't follow this practice or people will stop answering your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$ionicPopup.prompt` you can just make use of `$ionicPopup.show` and in template property of its object write whatever the template you want (with ng-model & ng-if). You can also have buttons with their customizable text as well as particular action onTap (like returning model value of input fields inside popup). So, you can have following function to call popup:

```
$scope.showPopup = function() {
   $scope.data = {}
   // An elaborate, custom popup
   var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
     template: '<input type="password" ng-if="isNotConnected" 
                ng-model="data.wifi" placeholder="Enter Password">',
     title: 'Enter Wi-Fi Password',
     subTitle: 'Please use normal things',
     scope: $scope,
     buttons: [
       { text: 'Cancel' },
       {
         text: '<b>Save</b>',
         type: 'button-positive',
         onTap: function(e) {
           if (!$scope.data.wifi) {
             //don't allow the user to close unless he enters wifi password
             e.preventDefault();
           } else {
             return $scope.data.wifi;
           }
         }
       },
     ]
   });
   myPopup.then(function(res) {
     console.log('Tapped!', res);
   });

};
```

Check out this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqwzPE